# R - Avoiding for loops with automatic iteration

Tags: r

This is a contrived example that I'm using to hopefully understand R better.  Lets say I want to subset a character vector called "test".  I want to return each element value from the third character to the last character.  This doesn't work:

```
test = c( "Jane" , "Jerry" , "Joan" )
substr( test , 3 , length( test ) )
expecting: "ne" , "rry" , "an"
```

Is there a way to do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `nchar()`. It's vectorized:

```
> test = c( "Jane" , "Jerry" , "Joan" )
> substr( test , 3 , nchar( test ) )
[1] "ne"  "rry" "an"
```

Given that nchar will return a vector of lengths, and that substr is likewise vectorized, and so expects to work with vector arguments, the one potential puzzle is why it even accepts a scalar argument of `3`. The answer here is that scalars to the start and stop arguments get recycled to match the length of the input character vector. You could, therefore, even  use 1:2 for the start argument and get alternating complete and almost complete strings:

```
>      substr( test , 1:2 , nchar( test ) )
[1] "Jane" "erry" "Joan"
```

Comment: @DWin - could you explain a bit more?

Comment: length(test) returns the number of the element in test, i.e., 3. Instead, you can use nchar for counting the number of characters.

Comment: OH!  I think I understand.  nchar iterates through each elment in test whereas length operates on the vector itself?  and the former is called "vectorized"?

Comment: I like this - the 'aha' moment :)

Comment: The other confusion you may experience with `length()` is when you use it on a dataframe. You might expect it to yield the number of rows, but it will in fact give the number of columns. Try it. `NROW()` is the right way to find out how many cases you have.